# Searching through multiple XML tags using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ViewCardResponse xmlns="http://schemas.com" schemaVersion="1.0">
    <CardActivations>
        <CardNumber>074125</CardNumber>
        <EffectiveFrom>2014-01-08</EffectiveFrom>
        <Status>InActive</Status>
      </CardActivations>
      <CardActivations>
        <CardNumber>074126</CardNumber>
        <EffectiveFrom>2014-01-08</EffectiveFrom>
        <Status>InActive</Status>
      </CardActivations>
      <CardActivations>
        <CardNumber>074127</CardNumber>
        <EffectiveFrom>2014-01-08</EffectiveFrom>
        <Status>Active</Status>
      </CardActivations>
</ViewCardResponse    >
```

And I have 3 fields.  I want to know the values of Cardnumber, effective from, and status of that cardactivation whose status is 'Active'. Can someone please suggest a LINQ query for this?

Answer (score 2):

```
XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(path);
var activeCards=doc.Elements()
                   .Where(x=>x.Element("Status").Value=="Active")
                   .Select(x=>
                          new 
                          {
                                CardNumber=x.Element("CardNumber").Value,
                                EffectiveFrom=x.Element("EffectiveFrom").Value
                          });
```